# What is @override annotation in java?

Tags: java, overriding

Why is NetBeans showing me a hint whenever I try to return a string from a method. Such as-

```
public String toString(){
  return "Circle: radius= "+radius+" color= "+color;
}
```

The hint says "`add @Override Annotation`"

Comment: because you override a method. If that annotiation is missing and parent function would change then you might run into some problem. The annotation warns you, if the corresponding method doesn´t override the method any more.

Comment: @KishanVaghela there is no need to, since it is showing the `toString` method, which initially comes from the `Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Override` annotation tells the compiler that you are **overriding** that method which is previously defined in a **super** class.

It helps the compiler verifying if in deed there is such a method defined in the super class or not. If it is not defined, you will get a compiler error telling you that the method is not defined in the **super** class.

If you are truely **overriding** an existing method defined in the **super** class, your code should work with or without the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Circle:  <script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/WOORli" type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: TestCircle: <script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/OiyWal" type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: Here is the whole code and I am just creating a new method here not overriding one.So why does the compiler think that I am overriding?

Comment: sorry, I don't do external **Javascript**. Update your post with the code **here**.

Comment: I think you can see the whole code by clicking on the links.Its ok not a big deal :)